# Tool to convert bitmap to vector graphic

Tags: windows, images, vector-graphics, media-converter

Any AI or software tool supports converting bitmap to vector graphic?

Example image from Wikipedia:

[image: Wikipedia]

Sample image i want to convert like this.
[image: Sample Image]

Comment: What should it recognize? English text and images that have been made using vector graphics in the first place?

Comment: Tools like the one described at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/121274/4039 do a very small part of what you want.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for reply and suggestion, It support for color?

Comment: I don't know, I only used that tool for monochrome. It is very limited, supporting only lines. Of course it does not support areas, even less gradients.

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for your suggestion.